# Rails has_one and accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I can't seem to get a has_one relationship with accepts_nested_attributes_for to work. This is my first foray into nested attributes, so it might be incorrect. Help!

Models:

```
class Case < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :logged_event, class_name: 'Event', dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :logged_event
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :case
  belongs_to :user
  validates :case, presence: true
  validates :user, presence: true
end
```

Controller:

```
class CasesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def new
    @case.build_logged_event(user: current_user)
  end

  def create
    if @case.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Case was successfully logged.'
      redirect_to cases_path
    else
      render 'cases/new'
    end
  end
end
```

Form:

```
<h1>New Case</h1>
<%= error_messages_for :case %>
<%= form_for(@case) do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label(:study) %>:
    <%= form.select(:study, Case.options_for(:study), include_blank: true) %>
  </p>
  <%= form.fields_for(:logged_event) do |logged_event_form| %>
    <%= logged_event_form.label(:created_at, 'Date Case was opened:') %>
    <%= logged_event_form.select(:created_at, [['Today', Date.today], ['Yesterday', Date.yesterday]]) %>
  <% end %>    
  <%= form.submit('Log Case') %> or <%= link_to('cancel', cases_path) %>
<% end %>
```

It's saying that the logged event is not getting a user id or a case id, so both validations on the event class are failing. It looks like:

There were problems with the following fields:
Logged event case can't be blank
Logged event user can't be blank

I don't get that, because in the new action I have already built the object. I also tried `form.fields_for(:logged_event, @case.logged_event)` but that didn't work either.

Comment: Could you paste the exact error message ?

Comment: Sure - pasted. It's the standard error message you get when you leave something blank.

Comment: The params passed after the submission contains the correct hash for `logged_event` attributes ?

Comment: No, I'm using Rails 3.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you shouldn't validate on both sides. I was validating that a case had an event and an event had a case. By removing the `validates :case, presence: true` like from event, everything worked as it should have.

Comment: You don't need to remove the validation if you set the `inverse_of` with the association. See my answer -- you can keep all your validations and avoid the errors too

Answer (score 0):

It's because `new` is not being called when you submit the form. Only the `create` action is being ran. So `@case` is populated only with the for submission data; no user or case is assigned to it since it's not in the form.

You'd need to assign the `user` and `case` properties of `@case` before trying to save (and running validations)

Comment: I'm using `CanCan` for that. That's the load_and_authorize_resource line.

Comment: Besides, @case doesn't have a user or a case, those are the Event class.

Comment: Ha right, I misread. Maybe when `load_and_authorize_resource` creates the event, it doesn't set the event's properties properly? Can you try setting `@case.logged_event.user` and `@case.logged_event.case` manually before calling `@case.save`?

Comment: I can, and will if I have to. But that defeats the entire purpose of using the nested attributes. I could just create the associated object in the controller every time, but I'm trying to allow it to override the default created_at for the logged_event.

Comment: That doesn't really defeats the nested attributes purpose (your logged events nested properties from the form still get automatically set). Nested attributes is there to allow you to set some properties automatically through form submission, some relations still have to be set manually.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove your validation -- you just need to add `inverse_of` to the association declaration to tell Rails to manage the back reference for you.

Your models should look like this:

```
class Case < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :logged_event, class_name: 'Event', dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :case
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :logged_event
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :case, inverse_of: :logged_event
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :logged_event # or inverse_of: :event -- you didn't provide your User model
  validates :case, presence: true
  validates :user, presence: true
end
```